# R data extraction data mean and sd

Tags: r, function

I have my code

```
V <- function(C, E, HS, EC_50) {
  response <- E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (C - EC_50)))
  list(response = response,
       mean_to_hist = mean(response),
       sd_to_hist = 1)
}


example1 <- V(seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1),0,1,log(1e-3))

example2 <-V(seq(-36, 0, by = 0.1),0,1,log(1e-3))

Fluorescence_Intensity <- function(X, MEAN, SD, METHOD){ 
  if(METHOD=="rnorm"){ 
    res <- rnorm(X, MEAN, SD) 
  } 
  if(METHOD=="dnorm"){ 
    res <- dnorm(X, MEAN, SD) 
  } 
  if(METHOD=="qnorm"){ 
    res <- qnorm(X, MEAN, SD, METHOD, LOWER.TAIL=NULL, LOG.P=NULL) 
  } 
  res
}

Fluorescence_Intensity <- function(X, MEAN, SD, METHOD){ 
  if(METHOD=="rnorm"){ 
    res <- rnorm(X, MEAN, SD) 
  } 
  if(METHOD=="dnorm"){ 
    res <- dnorm(X, MEAN, SD) 
  } 
  if(METHOD=="qnorm"){ 
    res <- qnorm(X, MEAN, SD, METHOD, LOWER.TAIL=NULL, LOG.P=NULL) 
  } 
  res
}

set.seed(2022)  # make the code reproducible
x <- Fluorescence_Intensity(X = 1000, MEAN = 2, SD = 1, METHOD = "rnorm")
y <- Fluorescence_Intensity(X = 1000, MEAN = 30, SD = 1, METHOD = "rnorm")
```

How can I change my code so that mean and sd for example1 become MEAN and SD for x i and the same for example2 and y respectively. Other than writing them  manually? I  don't how do it, so please help me

Answer (score 1):

What if you did something like this. The `...` would help to make it more flexible if you need to feed more arguments to the method. Also, this would make it so you don't need to hard code in all the methods you want to use.

```r
example1 <- V(seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1),0,1,log(1e-3))
example2 <-V(seq(-36, 0, by = 0.1),0,1,log(1e-3))

Fluorescence_Intensity <- function(my_V, METHOD, ...){ 
  fun <- METHOD
  fun(mean = my_V$mean_to_hist, sd = my_V$sd_to_hist, ...) 
}

x <- Fluorescence_Intensity(example1, rnorm, n = 100)
y <- Fluorescence_Intensity(example1, rnorm, n = 100)
```